# Value of textfield before "Editing Changed" event is fired

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to know if there is a way to know the value of textfield before the value is changed to the new value.

For example:

If the text field had a value "a" and the user entered "b", so the editing changed event is fired. When I try to fetch the value of the text field in the debugger it will display "ab". Is there a way that I can get "a" before "b" was written?

Here is a piece of code where I am trying to fetch the value:

```
@IBAction func commentEditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(!((sender as? UITextField)!.text!.isEmpty)){
        counter++
    }
    else
    {
        counter--
    }
}
```

In this case I want to know if the text was empty before the user entered text because I don't want the counter increments every time the user enters a character. I want to increment **once** the user entered any text.

And please don't propose to use delegate function `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` because my question is about this IBAction method.

If there is no way to do that using this IBAction Method, is there is any other IBAction method that can achieve what i want?

Comment: Since you don't want to use the delegate method you will need to store the  previous value in your own variable

Comment: @Paulw11 is there is any other IBAction method that can achieve what i want

Comment: No, an IBAction method only receives the `sender` - the text field and the action is triggered after the change, so you can only see the current, updated, state of the text field.  Due to the asynchronous nature of IBAction invocations it wouldn't be possible to reliably receive the 'before' state even if there was a theoretical 'Editing Will Change' event.  Delegate methods, on the other hand, are called synchronously, which is why you can access the 'before' state.

Comment: @MostafaMohamedRaafat You have Editing Did Begin method to get the value before editing

Comment: You always know the value before editing. Either it is a default you have set, or it is a stored value that you fetched and have put in the textfield. Anyway, I would use `Editing Did Begin` to know when a user starts editing. Or a `Bool` that is for example false and set to true by `Editing Changed` but only when it is false.